# Codeigniter Generate PDF for more than 1000 rows

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, pdf-generation

I have tried generate PDF file from CodeIgniter using PHPExcel, mPDF, TCPDF and HTML2PDF but there was a problem for generating more than 1000 rows fetching from MySQL. The problem start from memory exhausted also my xampp server needed to restart. Please share with me if you have successfully on generating PDF with more than 1000 rows. Thank's for your advise

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP's copy of php only uses a fixed amount of RAM, which might not be anywhere near your available resources. You may want to increase that based on your system.

```
File: \xampp\php\php.ini
memory_limit = 512M
```

Or any other number (in MB) of available RAM that you would like to allow PHP to use.

Comment: Thank's and this technique was implemented by me but still not help

Answer (score 0):

You could try to generate an html file and pass it through htmldoc. But if you are running in a low memory environment, even that may not work.

Comment: I have done it, and everything OK at HTML. I jsut add a button on HTML to generate PDF

Answer (score 0):

I use fpdf for my PDF creation and have hit plenty bigger than 1000 rows.

I'd suggest the issue is in your data creation phase from what you say above.  Can you output 1000 rows to HTML?

If not post the SQL etc and look at that instead

Comment: Everything OK retrieve to HTML, i suggest like you to, maybe there was some special character on my data so it occured an error generating using FPDF